# How to save data and layout of a fragment when moving to another fragment.?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a class which extends fragments. Also in action bar I have tabs to move to other fragments. But I want to save the data of the current fragment, so that when I come back to this fragments, the data is not reloaded. I have tried a few answers but none is working. Please help.

Here is the code:

**TopStoriesFragment.java**

```
    public class TopStoriesFragment extends Fragment {
    public String thehindu = "http://www.thehindu.com/?service=rss";
    public String currenturl = thehindu;
    AlertDialog levelDialog;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    ListView listView;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_stories,
                container, false);

        feedTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
        feedDescribtion = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.feeddescribtion);

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowDetails.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("keyTitle", myRssFeed.getItem(position)
                        .getTitle());
                bundle.putString("keyDescription", myRssFeed.getItem(position)
                        .getDescription());
                bundle.putString("keyLink", myRssFeed.getItem(position)
                        .getLink());
                bundle.putString("keyPubdate", myRssFeed.getItem(position)
                        .getPubdate());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        startReadRss();

        return rootView;
    }

    public class RssLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            displayRss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            preReadRss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            readRss();
            return null;
        }

    }

    private RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;

    TextView feedTitle;
    TextView feedDescribtion;

    // TextView feedPubdate;
    // TextView feedLink;

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<RSSItem> list) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null) {
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            }

            TextView listTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listtitle);
            listTitle.setText(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getTitle());
            TextView listPubdate = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.listpubdate);
            listPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getPubdate());

            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                listTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xff101010);
                listPubdate.setBackgroundColor(0xff101010);
            } else {
                listTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xff080808);
                listPubdate.setBackgroundColor(0xff080808);
            }

            return row;
        }
    }

    private void startReadRss() {
        new RssLoadingTask().execute();
    }

    private void preReadRss() {
        feedTitle.setText("--- wait ---");
        feedDescribtion.setText("");
        // feedPubdate.setText("");
        // feedLink.setText("");
        listView.setAdapter(null);

        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reading RSS, Please wait.",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        // .show();
    }

    private void readRss() {

        try {
            URL rssUrl = new URL(currenturl);
            SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory
                    .newInstance();
            SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
            RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
            myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
            InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
            myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

            myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void displayRss() {
        if (myRssFeed != null) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            // String strCurrentTiime = "\n(Time of Reading - "
            // + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
            // + " Hrs. : "
            // + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " Mins.)\n" +c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "MMMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
            String strCurrentTiime = sdf.format(c.getTime());

            feedTitle.setText(myRssFeed.getTitle());
            feedDescribtion.setText(strCurrentTiime);
            // feedPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getPubdate());
            // feedLink.setText(myRssFeed.getLink());

            MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.row, myRssFeed.getList());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Stories", "National", "International", "Sports", "Technology", "Business", "Entertainment"};

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

I have more fragments like topstories and I want to save data of one when moving to other.

Comment: What if you implement a callback to the activity and then the activity will save and relay the data to the next fragment.

Comment: Have you tried using the backstack?